# BeautifulSoup AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data off of this URL and getting an error on this part of my scraper, the full chunk of code is below

```
if table.find_all('tr'):
```

Note I previously had built it without the `if/elif/else` logic and just `find_all('tr')`, but it produces the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "statbunker.py", line 217, in <module>
    if table.find_all('tr'):        
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ds383/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 921, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

```
    link = 'https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/MatchDetails/World-Cup-2019/Japan-VS-Russia?comp_id=606&match_id=39737&date=20-Sep-2019'
    response = requests.get(link)
    html_loop = response.content
    soup_loop = BeautifulSoup(html_loop, 'html.parser')

    home_substititions = soup_loop.find('table', {'id': 'homeSubs'})
    for table in home_substititions.find('tbody'):
        if table.find_all('tr'):        
            for row in table.find_all('tr'):
                substitutionEvent = {}
                substitutionEvent['uuid'] = uuid.uuid1()
                substitutionEvent['playerIn'] = row.find_all('td')[2].text
                substitutionEvent['playerOut'] = row.find_all('td')[4].text
                if int(row.find_all('td')[0].text.split('`')[0]):
                    substitutionEvent['subTime'] = game['gameTime'] + timedelta.Timedelta(minutes=int(row.find_all('td')[0].text.split('`')[0]))
                else:
                    substitutionEvent['subTime'] = ''
                homeSubstitutionEvents.append(substitutionEvent)
        elif table.find('tr'):
            for row in table.find('tr'):
                substitutionEvent = {}
                substitutionEvent['uuid'] = uuid.uuid1()
                substitutionEvent['playerIn'] = row.find_all('td')[2].text
                substitutionEvent['playerOut'] = row.find_all('td')[4].text
                if int(row.find_all('td')[0].text.split('`')[0]):
                    substitutionEvent['subTime'] = game['gameTime'] + timedelta.Timedelta(minutes=int(row.find_all('td')[0].text.split('`')[0]))
                else:
                    substitutionEvent['subTime'] = ''
                homeSubstitutionEvents.append(substitutionEvent)
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020762/beautifulsoup-attributeerror-navigablestring-object-has-no-attribute-find/52021014 help you ?

Comment: @Simplecode not exactly... I am able to find the table, but I am getting an error on the <tr> tag inside of the table, and there's no `id` or other attributes on the <tr> tag which I can use to further select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did some little changes. the problem was that you put `for table in yourstuff.find('sth')` but you were finding just one element so no need for loop

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://rugby.statbunker.com/competitions/MatchDetails/World-Cup-2019/Japan-VS-Russia?comp_id=606&match_id=39737&date=20-Sep-2019'
response = requests.get(link)
html_loop = response.content
soup_loop = BeautifulSoup(html_loop, 'html.parser')

home_substititions = soup_loop.find('table', {'id': 'homeSubs'})
table = home_substititions.find('tbody')
print(table)
if table.find_all('tr'):
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        substitutionEvent = {}
        substitutionEvent['uuid'] = uuid.uuid1()
        substitutionEvent['playerIn'] = row.find_all('td')[2].text
        substitutionEvent['playerOut'] = row.find_all('td')[4].text
        if int(row.find_all('td')[0].text.split('`')[0]):
            substitutionEvent['subTime'] = game['gameTime'] + timedelta.Timedelta(minutes=int(row.find_all('td')[0].text.split('`')[0]))
        else:
            substitutionEvent['subTime'] = ''
        homeSubstitutionEvents.append(substitutionEvent)
elif table.find('tr'):
    for row in table.find('tr'):
        substitutionEvent = {}
        substitutionEvent['uuid'] = uuid.uuid1()
        substitutionEvent['playerIn'] = row.find_all('td')[2].text
        substitutionEvent['playerOut'] = row.find_all('td')[4].text
        if int(row.find_all('td')[0].text.split('`')[0]):
            substitutionEvent['subTime'] = game['gameTime'] + timedelta.Timedelta(minutes=int(row.find_all('td')[0].text.split('`')[0]))
        else:
            substitutionEvent['subTime'] = ''
        homeSubstitutionEvents.append(substitutionEvent)
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, using `.find()` will return only tags/navigablestring combinations, you have to use `.find_all()` to iterate:

```
home_substititions = soup_loop.find_all('table', {'id': 'homeSubs'})
    for table in home_substititions:
        # ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that home_substititions is not a BeautifulSoup class, not as soup_loop

```
type (home_substititions)
type (soup_loop)
```

The output will be

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
```

For your code to work you will need to apply the find and find_all to the original soup